# Why "mat2" show over 90 lines of metadata for video file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, metadata

I bought a video and see a lot of meta data. What do these metadata mean (overview summary)? Is there something like watermarking to track who the owner is?

```
mat2 -s video.mp4
[+] Metadata for video.mp4:
    AltTimecodeTimeFormat: 59.94 fps (drop)
    AltTimecodeTimeValue: 00;00;00;00
    AudioChannelType: Stereo
    AudioSampleType: 16-bit integer
    CompatibleBrands: ['M4V ', 'mp42', 'isom']
    CompressorID: avc1
    CompressorName: AVC Coding
    CreateDate: 2020:11:09 16:44:55+01:00
    CreatorTool: Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC 2015 (Windows)
    DerivedFromDocumentID: xmp.did:9902b825-8b27-5640-8b76-5b136d0ea7bc
    DerivedFromInstanceID: xmp.iid:9902b825-8b27-5640-8b76-5b136d0ea7bc
    DerivedFromOriginalDocumentID: xmp.did:9902b825-8b27-5640-8b76-5b136d0ea7bc
    DocumentID: 5a89b15b-f7e0-b162-e166-0b7a00000067
    DurationScale: 1.11111111111111e-05
    DurationValue: 110674560
    Format: H.264
    GraphicsMode: srcCopy
    HandlerDescription: Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
    HandlerType: Audio Track
    HistoryAction: ['saved', 'created', 'saved', 'saved']
    HistoryChanged: ['/', '/', '/metadata']
    HistoryInstanceID: ['4b3b2d68-3464-3bb6-6b32-91ae00000094', 'xmp.iid:9902b825-8b27-5640-8b76-5b136d0ea7bc', 'xmp.iid:0e612392-7976-c741-a822-a721f06a13d2', 'xmp.iid:ee31c5e9-1517-db48-89dd-bd9f236f32fb']
    HistorySoftwareAgent: ['Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC 2015 (Windows)', 'Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC 2015 (Windows)', 'Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC 2015 (Windows)', 'Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC 2015 (Windows)']
    HistoryWhen: ['2020:11:09 16:45:21+01:00', '2020:11:09 15:30:46+01:00', '2020:11:09 16:45:20+01:00', '2020:11:09 16:45:21+01:00']
    IngredientsDocumentID: ['17d3872e-9a9e-e174-72e0-716700000057', 'b9b25f0e-f7c9-a41a-9ffb-990e00000055', 'xmp.did:2aac4b58-91ac-1046-8ed3-a632d3ae5192', 'xmp.did:a1ebf30e-ed51-aa41-92ae-7cb05987f820']
    IngredientsFilePath: ['movie_ending_1080p.png', 'movie_title_1080p.png', 'Sequenz 01', 'Sequenz 01']
    IngredientsFromPart: ['time:0', 'time:0', 'time:0d309815300995200f254016000000', 'time:0d309815300995200f254016000000']
    IngredientsInstanceID: ['21f83c33-fb22-c75f-e179-ad5700000084', '53c709c5-de60-8ea3-930a-66f400000082', 'xmp.iid:2aac4b58-91ac-1046-8ed3-a632d3ae5192', 'xmp.iid:a1ebf30e-ed51-aa41-92ae-7cb05987f820']
    IngredientsMaskMarkers: ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
    IngredientsToPart: ['time:311086651075200f254016000000d1271350080000f254016000000', 'time:0d1271350080000f254016000000', 'time:1271350080000f254016000000d309815300995200f254016000000', 'time:1271350080000f254016000000d309815300995200f254016000000']
    InstanceID: xmp.iid:ee31c5e9-1517-db48-89dd-bd9f236f32fb
    MacAtomApplicationCode: 1347449455
    MacAtomInvocationAppleEvent: 1129468018
    MajorBrand: Apple iTunes Video (.M4V) Video
    MediaCreateDate: 2020:11:09 15:44:55
    MediaDataOffset: 897778
    MediaDataSize: 1588632083
    MediaHeaderVersion: 0
    MediaLanguageCode: eng
    MediaModifyDate: 2020:11:09 15:44:55
    MetadataDate: 2020:11:09 16:45:21+01:00
    MinorVersion: 0.0.1
    ModifyDate: 2020:11:09 16:45:21+01:00
    MovieHeaderVersion: 0
    NextTrackID: 3
    OriginalDocumentID: xmp.did:a508c79a-2272-c546-91d4-c9aa4c498a90
    PantryCreateDate: 2020:11:07 14:03:57Z
    PantryCreatorTool: Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Windows)
    PantryDerivedFromDocumentID: xmp.did:34B7DA9CD49AE6118979968F31FD9306
    PantryDerivedFromInstanceID: xmp.iid:D6D95BF95B20EB11B0ABB873A4E7C38E
    PantryDocumentID: xmp.did:fe7bc376-e888-ee4c-b3a1-708f3e7caaad
    PantryDurationScale: 1.11111111111111e-05
    PantryDurationValue: 12977280
    PantryHistoryAction: saved
    PantryHistoryChanged: /metadata
    PantryHistoryInstanceID: xmp.iid:fe7bc376-e888-ee4c-b3a1-708f3e7caaad
    PantryHistorySoftwareAgent: Adobe Adobe Media Encoder CC 2015 (Windows)
    PantryHistoryWhen: 2020:11:09 15:30:46+01:00
    PantryIngredientsDocumentID: f3d8f942-f860-44ed-270d-82bf00000045
    PantryIngredientsFilePath: vid011++o.mp4
    PantryIngredientsFromPart: time:42336000000f254016000000d14148691200000f254016000000
    PantryIngredientsInstanceID: b7e0bd35-580a-727e-0779-f5ce00000072
    PantryIngredientsMaskMarkers: None
    PantryIngredientsToPart: time:42336000000f254016000000d14148691200000f254016000000
    PantryInstanceID: xmp.iid:fe7bc376-e888-ee4c-b3a1-708f3e7caaad
    PantryMarked: False
    PantryMetadataDate: 2020:11:09 15:30:46+01:00
    PantryModifyDate: 2020:11:09 15:30:45+01:00
    PantryOriginalDocumentID: xmp.did:fe7bc376-e888-ee4c-b3a1-708f3e7caaad
    PreferredRate: 1
    ProjectRefType: Movie
    Rotation: 0
    StartTimeSampleSize: 1001
    StartTimeScale: 60000
    StartTimecode: 00;00;00;00
    StartTimecodeTimeFormat: 59.94 fps (drop)
    StartTimecodeTimeValue: 00;00;00;00
    TimeScale: 90000
    TrackCreateDate: 2020:11:09 15:44:55
    TrackHeaderVersion: 0
    TrackID: 1
    TrackLayer: 0
    TrackModifyDate: 2020:11:09 15:44:55
    VideoFieldOrder: Progressive
    VideoFrameSizeH: 1080
    VideoFrameSizeUnit: pixel
    VideoFrameSizeW: 1920
    VideoPixelAspectRatio: 1
    WindowsAtomExtension: .prproj
    WindowsAtomInvocationFlags: /L
    WindowsAtomUncProjectPath: movie_frame_1080p_cc2015.prproj
    XMPToolkit: Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c067 79.157747, 2015/03/30-23:40:42
```

Comment: They are not tracking buyers - those are metadata written by the authoring program (Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015).

Comment: All those `Ingredients*` and `Pantry*` tags are XMP tags which are really easy to remove.  Either remux the file with ffmpeg or with [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) you would run `exiftool -XMP:all= video.mp4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no need to worry about those meta data or why you should remove them.

Pantry and Ingredients tags refer to asset tracking. In fact most of this data are production related and not relevant in any way for a consumer. The rest tells you about technical features, like the resolution or video codec.

A watermark is something different. If you want to protect digital data you typically use DRM or could hide it steganographically in the video content or even make it plainly visible. Metadata can be removed too easily and are not used for this purpose.